# Issue in custom Mute/UnMute functionality in react-jw-player

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jwplayer, mobx, mobx-react

I have used **react-jw-player** for one of my react project.

I need to add one custom button for mute/unmute video player. I have implemented **mobx** to update options values. It updates the values but it does not reflect the jwPlayer.

First I have tried without **mobx** and it works but it reloads the whole player, so my playlist starts playing from the first. So I decided to setup **mobx** in that. It updates the data but then it will not reflect on the player.

**PlayerStore.js**

```
class PlayerStore {

    @observable isMute = true;

    @action muteUnmuteVideo = (isMute) => {
        this.isMute = isMute;
    }
}

var Store = new PlayerStore();

export default Store;
```

**MuteButton.js**

```
@inject('Store')

export class MuteButton extends Component {

    constructor(props) {

        super(props);
        this.state = {isMute: true};

        // This binding is necessary to make `this` work in the callback
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }

    handleClick() {

        this.setState(prevState => ({
            isMute: !prevState.isMute
        }));

        this.props.Store.muteUnmuteVideo(this.state.isMute);
    }

    render() {
        return (

            <button onClick={this.handleClick} className="btn mute-btn" id="mute-btn">Click Here</button>
        );
    }
}
export default MuteButton;
```

**CustomJwPlayer.js**

```
@inject('Store')
@observer
export class CustomJwPlayer extends Component {

    render() {

        const  { Store, playlist, isAutoPlay, isMuted, customProps } = this.props;

        return (

            <div className="full-height" >

                <ReactJWPlayer
                    className="single-player"
                    playerId='my-unique-id'
                    playerScript='https://content.jwplatform.com/libraries/4hK3AT2X.js'
                    playlist={playlist}
                    isAutoPlay={isAutoPlay}
                    isMuted={Store.isMute}
                    customProps={{ 
                        controls: false,
                        repeat: true,
                        defaultBandwidthEstimate: 400000,
                        stretching: 'fill',
                        preload: 'auto',
                        volume: 100,
                        width: '100%',
                        height: '100%',
                    }}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default CustomJwPlayer;
```

Comment: please go through the bugs section of this library on github,i think there is bug in the library

Comment: I have checked that but I am not able to find any proper answer. I have posted my questions over there as well but I haven't got any response.

Answer (score 0):

try to use setState callback

```
handleClick() {
    this.setState({
        isMute: !this.state.isMute
    }, () => {
    this.props.Store.muteUnmuteVideo(this.state.isMute);
  });
}
```

Comment: @Rav'sPatel Is there `observer` decorator? if it isn't, try this import { inject, observer } from 'mobx-react'  and add @observer below @inject('Store')

Comment: yes it's already there. Store values are updated successfully but it will not reflect on the jwplayer component.